# functional equation with exact solution for a power function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

let be the equation $$ x^{x^{x}}=a $$

this is a trascendental equation but depending of which values of 'a' does the equation a solution?

for example if $$ a=b^{{b}^{b}} $$

but are there other alternatives

Comment: I'm having trouble following your question. Am I right in thinking that you want to know, for what values of $a$ does $x^{x^x} = a$ have *at least one* solution, and if that solution is unique?

Comment: not if the solution is unique but if the solutions are exact, for example for a=16 we get x=2

Comment: What does exact mean? Do you mean, under what conditions can we find a closed form for $x$?